# Is it possible to scope a broadcast to an application?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

I want to use sendBroadcast to broadcast an intent that can only be received by that application that originated it.

The use case is for an authentication module I'm planning to use between several projects I've built. Currently when a 401 (authorization failed) response code is received it broadcasts an intent that can then be wired in the manifest to bring the user back to the login page.

So just to be clear I'm wondering if I can do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent("my.custom.logout.broadcast.path.that.will.be.the.same.in.multiple.apps");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

And somehow the intent doesn't get picked up by other apps that use exactly the same un-modified code base.

Comment: You could put data in the intent and add logic to each app to only act upon an intent with data specific to that application. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem of using existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not part of the question, but you should be using [permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Permissions) for restricting who can send/receive the Broadcasts, especially since you're dealing with authentication.  In fact, I would highly recommend looking into the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) (in [API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html))

Moving on.. one solution is to pass the originating application's package name or a particular permission string in an Intent extra, and when you respond, use that package name or permission in the response, the same way.  Unfortunately you can't target a specific package in a Broadcast Intent.

Yet another solution, is using [`PendingIntent.getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) from the originating application, stuff that `PendingIntent` into the new for-broadcast `Intent` as an extra (`Intent#putExtra()`) and broadcast it using the permissions model above (so sender and receiver can handle permissions properly).  When the broadcast receiver has finished doing its thing, it can use the `PendingIntent` to start the target activity (including the ability to attach additional extras)

Comment: I like the idea of passing an intent extra. Thanks for that. I think it'll fit my solution perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the LocalBroadcastManager, which is specifically designed for in-app communication.

Comment: But not inter-process